# OnChange of SwitchCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TableView with a SwitchCell. I would like to add an OnChanged event to it. How would i acheive that,? If possible, My code below:

```
 TableView tvProfile = new TableView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot {
                new TableSection ("Active")
                {
                    (new  SwitchCell {Text = "Pause Timer" } )
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to keep a reference to the switch class when you create it, and use that to assign the handler:

```
SwitchCell switch;

TableView tvProfile = new TableView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot {
                new TableSection ("Active")
                {
                    (switch = new  SwitchCell {Text = "Pause Timer" } )
                }
            }
        };

switch.OnChanged += (s,e) => {
  // handler logic goes here
};
```